# AngularJS and Edmunds Media API to create MAKE MODEL YEAR drop downs, then display Vehicle Images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

--**TASK**-- Get the MEDIA API after drop down has been selected ( Make Model Year).

--**CONDITION**-- getting 'undefined' error. Yes able to correctly fill the drop downs with Make, Model, Year, but when try to pass that result to the MEDIA $http.get it gives - 'undefined'.

**ANGULAR**

```
// *CONNECT & GET - LIST OF CAR MAKES*
// http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?fmt=json&api_key={api key}

$http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?fmt=json&api_key=' + api_key )
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.carMakes = data.makes; 
        console.log($scope.carMakes); 
        console.log($scope.carMakes[4].name); // Audi

        $scope.carModels = $scope.carMakes[4].models;
        console.log($scope.carModels[4].name); // A3


        $scope.carYears = $scope.carMakes[4].models[4].years[8]; 
        console.log($scope.carYears.year); // 2015

});

$scope.selectedCar.carmake = $scope.carMakes[4]; // <-ERROR HERE - 'undefined'

$scope.edmundsMake = "AUDI";
$scope.edmundsModel = "A3";
$scope.edmundsYear = "2015";

//GET the edmunds media api 
//Make Model Year photos
    $http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/media/v2/' + $scope.selectedCar.carmake + '/' + $scope.edmundsModel + '/' + $scope.edmundsYear + '/photos?title=&category=exterior&provider=oem&width=1280&shottype=S&pagenum=1&pagesize=10&view=basic&api_key='+ api_key +'&fmt=json')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.carImages = data.photos;
            });
```

**HTML** - YES WORKS ; creates the 3 drop downs for MAKE > MODEL > YEAR

```
 <div id="mmy" class="mmy">
    <div class="selectDdown col-lg-4 selectLabels">
    <!--  DROPDOWN of CarTypes by Carmake  -->

   <label for="{{ selectedCar.carmake }}"> Make  </label>
      <select ng-model="selectedCar.carmake" 
              ng-options="carMake.name for carMake in carMakes" 
              id="{{selectedCar.carmake}}"
              size="1">
              <option value=""> Make </option>
      </select>    
    </div>
```

```
    <!--  DROPDOWN of car models  -->
    <div class="selectDdown col-lg-4 selectLabels">
    <label for="{{ selectedCar.model }}"> Model </label>
      <select ng-model="selectedCar.model" 
              ng-options="carModel.name for carModel in selectedCar.carmake.models"
              id="{{selectedCar.model}}"
              size="1">
              <option value=""> Model </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!--  DROPDOWN of years  -->
    <div class="selectDdown col-lg-4 selectLabels">
    <label for="{{ selectedCar.year }}"> Year  </label>
      <select ng-model="selectedCar.year" 
              ng-options="y.year for y in selectedCar.model.years" 
              id="{{selectedCar.year}}"
              size="1">
              <option value=""> Year </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you expect ```$scope.carMakes[4]; ``` to return. As it is an object you will need to use something like a ```push``` method

Comment: if I do $scope.carMakes[4].name;  - error says cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Any help is appreciated. Thank you (Paul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` is an asynchronous function. This means that `$scope.carMakes` isn't available until your success function returns.

Change your code to look like this:

```
$http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?fmt=json&api_key=' + api_key )
.success(function (data) {
  $scope.carMakes = data.makes; 
  $scope.selectedCar.carmake = $scope.carMakes[4];
  ...
  $http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/media/v2/' + $scope.selectedCar.carmake + '/' + $scope.edmundsModel + '/' + $scope.edmundsYear + '/photos?title=&category=exterior&provider=oem&width=1280&shottype=S&pagenum=1&pagesize=10&view=basic&api_key='+ api_key +'&fmt=json')
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.carImages = data.photos;
    });
});
```

Comment: (Azium), Thank you very much.
$scope.selectedCar.carmake = $scope.carMakes[4].name; //Audi

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line for setting the initially selected into the callback for the AJAX request since it's async

```
$scope.carMakes = data.makes; 
$scope.selectedCar.carmake = $scope.carMakes[4];
```

Also make sure to intialize selectedCar, $scope.selectedCar = {}; sometime before this.

Comment: yes, thank you for reminder to initialize selectedCar. (was doing that but always helps to get reminded )